# Update iPhone app info without going through apple

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, rss

i was wondering, i have a little experience making iPhone apps but no coding background in anything and was wondering.... Is there a way to update your iPhone app with new text, pictures, colors, links, etc. without manually doing it from Xcode then having to get the new version approved by apple.

I was hoping to be able to update it from possibly from my website. Any easy way to do this? Preferably the easiest solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, but you have to design the application to do it from the start. Instead of reading from the app itself, the app reads from a content management system (CMS) or even just a text file stored on your website. Many apps work this way, but you will need to design the app with this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

For the amount of things you need updated, I would create a iPhone optimized version of your website and in your app, all you would need is a web view that takes the user to your website. So to change content, you could just change your website and the user will think that the app is getting updated. One thing to keep in mind though, if the user doesn't have internet connection or if there internet is slow, the site my not show up at all or be very slow to respond and load. Hope this helps.

Comment: Apple tends to reject apps that are nothing but a webview to a website.

Comment: Really? Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I did not know that!